# Actualizar información de la base de datos en tiempo real

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, hilos

quisiera saber como se podría actualizar mi base de datos de manera automática. Las tecnologías que he escuchado son Socket.io, pero como se podría implementar socket.io con python? ó que otra tecnología recomiendan para Django Python?.

Este es mi modelo:

**models.py**

```
class Model(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    number = models.FloatField(default=0)
```

Realice el siguiente código que actualiza de manera automática por medio de hilos (Threads) el campo number del modelo Model, se empiezan a actualizar los datos cada minuto una vez el usuario haya mandado la información de mi formulario por método POST, pero la falla del código es que solo se actualiza si el usuario manda información del formulario, porque la petición ejecuta el Hilo que llama a la función actualizar y cuando finaliza de ejecutarse se vuelve a llamar a si misma. De esta manera sería como un ciclo.

**views.py**

```
import threading
import time 

def actualizar(request):
    user = request.user
    x = Model.objects.all().filter(user=request.user)

    for i in x:
        i.number = variable_z
        i.save()

    time.sleep(60)

    thread = threading.Thread(target=actualizar, args=(request,))
    thread.start()
```

Pero ahora como se podría hacer lo mismo, pero que se actualice de manera automática cada minuto todo el tiempo?

Muchas gracias amigos, saludos

Comment: No podrías guardar la fecha de registro del usuario, y cuando quieras obtener o utilizar la variable `number` lo único que tendrías que hacer es sacar la diferencia en minutos entre la fecha actual y la fecha de registro?

Comment: ¿Pero qué problema tiene tu código? Tal como está tu publicación parece que estás pidiendo que alguien escriba toda la solución para ti. Las preguntas sobre depuración deberían incluir algún mensaje de error. Busca 'Django Channels'  en Google.

Comment: Hola toledano, más que nada es para darles la idea de lo que quiero hacer y de esa manera me pudieran brindar su opinion sobre que tecnología podría implementar para realizar la misma tarea que plante, nose por ejemplo (ajax, sockeot.io etc..) y si conocen documentación de la misma para python para que yo la revise o asi, y conforme a tu pregunta, el código funciona correctamente, pero crees que se podría hacer ese mismo código de otra manera con alguna otra tecnologìa?

Comment: @Genarito, si puede ser,  alguna idea de como podría ser en código amigo?, gracias Genarito

Comment: Ahi respondí @YamamotoAY. Espero que te sea de ayuda! Saludos! :D

Answer (score 0):

No hace falta hacer un método que se ejecute cada minuto. Eso desperdiciaría muchos recursos, con código sucio de por medio.

Lo que puedes hacer es calcular el atributo `number` solo cuando es solicitado:

Primero **definimos una fecha de registro del usuario** que se va a setear una única vez (cuando se crea):

```
class Model(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    registration_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=False)
```

Luego podemos Hacer un atributo property dentro de tu clase `Model`:

```
class Model(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    registration_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=False)

    @property
    def number(self):
        "Devuelve el atributo number. Que es igual a la cantidad 
        de minutos que transcurrieron desde que se dio de alta al modelo"
        today = datetime.now()
        return '%d' % ((today - self.registration_date) * 24 * 60)  # Devuelvo la difererencia en minutos
```

Ahora podemos hacer en cualquier lugar donde quieras el atributo:

```
x = Model.objects.all().filter(user=request.user)
x.number
```

Espero que te haya sido de ayuda!

Saludos